# Jetpack Compose Lottie Dynamic Text and Image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I have a json animation that I'm using with LottieAnimation, but my feature needs that I change a text and an image inside the animation in runtime.

The animation is a ranking like a podium. Then animated winner text and image are loaded from the backend. So I need to set these values.

Right now I know that TextDelegate can handle the Text problem, but it only works with View, as the old way to do it. It needs the View in constructor. I don't find a way to do this with Compose. And about the image, I have no glues.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your `json` file structure, you have two ways of settings an image

1. Place used images inside `src/main/assets/lottieImages`. Names should be the same as mentioned in your `json` file, in my case it's `img_0.png`.

```kotlin
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.we_accept),
    imageAssetsFolder = "lottieImages"
)
```

2. Set a bitmap to key path, like I'm taking it from the resources, using dynamic properties

```kotlin
val bitmap = remember {
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.my_image)
}
val dynamicProperties = rememberLottieDynamicProperties(
    rememberLottieDynamicProperty(LottieProperty.IMAGE, bitmap, "weaccept.jpg"),
)
LottieAnimation(
    composition,
    dynamicProperties = dynamicProperties
)
```

I'm using [this json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airbnb/lottie-android/194d96df4d50d5c4376a6547f72698e81abb28d0/sample-compose/src/main/res/raw/we_accept.json) as a sample animation.

As for the text, Lottie `TextDelegate` does not seem to be ported to compose, I suggest you [create](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/new/choose) a feature request on github.